# Remove popups that are caused by custom actions - Wix

Tags: wix, installation, fatal-error, custom-action, wix3.8

Newbie to wix, I am learning it. I had initially set up some custom actions for installing/ uninstalling/ rollback actions. These custom actions cause unintended popups during installation. I am trying to remove the same using SetProperty, DllEntry and BinaryKey. This is  my original code:

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallStorageService"
              Directory="ProductAppDataFolder"
              ExeCommand='[ProductAppDataFolder]bin\install_service.bat "[InstallationFolder]" "[ProductAppDataFolder]" "$(var.StorageServiceName)"'
              Execute="deferred"
              Impersonate="no"
              Return="check"/>
```

This is what I have changed it to:

```
<SetProperty Id="InstallStorageService"  
             Value="cmd.exe /c [PRODUCTAPPDATAFOLDER]bin\install_service.bat &quot;[InstallationFolder]&quot; &quot;[ProductAppDataFolder]&quot; &quot;$(var.StorageServiceName)&quot;"
             After="CostFinalize"/>

<CustomAction Id="InstallStorageService"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              Execute="deferred" 
              Return="check"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Impersonate="yes"/>
```

I have done similarly for removing and for rollback actions. I do not get any errors or issues while I run the `.bat` file to create the `msi` file, but once the `msi` is created, I am having trouble installing it. I can share the log file if required, but there are fatal errors with not much of verbose about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html) pattern to invoke out of process exe's and scripts.  The pattern will capture stderr and stdout to the Windows Installer log.

However it would be better to not use a .BAT as self registration (in all forms) is not a windows installer best practice.  See [Zataoca: Custom actions are (generally) an admission of failure.](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/zataoca-custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure/)